# How to design options in select box scroll bar after clicked by user using css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is there any options to design the select box option tag scroll bars to apply color or any other designs
 i have tried these css to style scroll bar it works fine other than select box option tag

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 10px;
} /* this targets the default scrollbar (compulsory) */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  /*background-color: #1484E8;*/
} /* the new scrollbar will have a flat appearance with the set background color */

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #1484E8; 
} /* this will style the thumb, ignoring the track */

::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
  /*background-color: #153889;*/
} /* optionally, you can style the top and the bottom buttons (left and right for horizontal bars) */

::-webkit-scrollbar-corner {
  /*background-color: transparent;*/
} /* if both the vertical and the horizontal bars appear, then perhaps the right bottom corner also needs to be styled */
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript

Comment: Thanks  mplungjan but those code explain how to design select box view but i want to design the scroll bar after the user clicked